# MSBuild custom task not fired in Visual Studio 2013

Tags: c#, visual-studio, msbuild, visual-studio-2013, msbuild-task

In my `solution` I have a project with this single class:

```
using System.Windows;
using Microsoft.Build.Utilities;

namespace MetaCode
{
    public class MsBuildTask : AppDomainIsolatedTask
    {
        public override bool Execute()
        {
            System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Run(() => MessageBox.Show("12345678"));
            Log.LogMessage("12345678");
            return true;
        }
    }
}
```

I added this to another project's `csproj` file (let's call this project "Genesis" for now):

```
<Project ToolsVersion="4.0" DefaultTargets="Build" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
    <UsingTask TaskName="MetaCode.MsBuildTask" AssemblyFile="c:\temp\MetaCode.dll" />
    ...
    <Target Name="AfterBuild">
        <MetaCode.MsBuildTask />
    </Target>
</Project>
```

But when I hit <kbd>F5</kbd> in **Visual Studio 2013 Pro**, it builds the projects fine, but nothing happens... No `MessageBox` showing `"12345678"`, and no `"12345678"` text in the "output" panel in Visual Studio. What am I missing here?

(the file "c:\temp\MetaCode.dll" exists in that location, and this is the output file of the above "MetaCode" project)

Comment: That doesn't prove much.  Message boxes are suppressed, nobody ever likes their build server to freeze on them.  And you'd only see the log message when you crank up the build verbosity.

Comment: @HansPassant, so how can I be sure that it works? create some file maybe?

Comment: You'd expect a build task to have an observable outcome.  If there isn't any at all then there's no point in using it :)

Comment: Agreed.  A messagebox in a Msbuild task would be brutal.  As a test, I would take a string input, and take that string and append it to the DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString() and return the value to the (exterior) .proj file....and write it out there.

Comment: This is my preferred method for debugging custom msbuild tasks.  http://blogs.msdn.com/b/msbuild/archive/2005/09/28/474951.aspx

Comment: @HansPassant, how does that help to state the obvious? although that was a cynical remark, my practical response is that I want to try creating "observable outcomes", but these are new to me too, so if no observable outcome is seen, then what? is the problem in the MSBuild task or in the supposed-to-be-observable-outcome? I am 99% sure that you already know all the answers provided by the other users, that were very helpful (actually resolved the problem), so why not just being kind and help young/beginner programmers? Thank you on your first comment though, that helped with some guidance.

Comment: Stating the obvious in comments is, unfortunately, some times necessary.  I guessed that you didn't have a real problem, turned out that this was a correct guess.  You've enriched the SO site with an answer to a non-existing problem, not what we are trying to do here.  If you don't know how to increase the build output verbosity then ask a question about it.

Comment: @HansPassant, why not just simply answer? if I knew exactly what was the problem (verbosity? `MSBuild` file mistake? coding mistake?), then, well, I don't need SO. Alternatively, a suggestion for title-change would be much more kind and polite. Isn't creating an unpleasant environment misses some of SO's goals? "You've enriched the SO site with an answer to a non-existing problem" you said, put aside the fact that my problem is very "existing" to me (maybe not only to me?), if somebody gets here to understand why his `custom task` doesn't fire, then haven't I enriched SO with valuable content?

Comment: Those comments were meant to help you get unstuck on a silly problem.  If you hate them that much then simply flag a moderator and he'll delete them for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- First, increase message verbosity:

  ```
  Log.LogMessage(MessageImportance.High, "12345678");
  ```

And add a standard message just to make sure:

```
<Target Name="AfterBuild">
    <Message Text="About to run MsBuildTask" Importance="high" />
    <MetaCode.MsBuildTask />
</Target>
```

- Using task manager, kill all `MSBuild.exe` processes to clear all previous versions of your custom task.
- Rebuild the MSBuild task.
- Rebuild the consumer project and watch the output pane.